# Bootstrap sidebar changes sizes when content is added

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently built my personal website, but I'm having some trouble with the sidebar. Its currently live at normanmu.com, and as you can see the sidebar on the landing page is a slightly different size than the sidebar on my blog page or my projects page. When I remove all content it turns out that the landing page sidebar is the normal length and somehow adding the page contents shrinks the size by about 5px. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try setting `height: 100%; width: 100%` for your html and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

When resizing the page, the sidebar seems to take over the entire page.  Take a look at this: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/.  It is free and includes the css and html in the download zip for adding a great responsive sidebar to your website.